# Matplotlib Basemap Hexbin Animation: Clear hexbins between frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm animating a hexbin heatmap over a basemap image, but can't figure out how to remove the previous hexes before starting the next frame. I want to animate with some accumulation, but reset at chosen intervals (my data has a time dimension, I want to show all points for a given year, day by day, then wipe the hexes and show the following year). I guess I need to store the layer, and use its .remove() method, but I can't figure it out.

```
def update_hex(i, prev_layer):
  if i == (len(years) - 1):
    ani.event_source.stop()
    print("End animation: Update Hex")

  x, y = [mm.xmin, mm.xmax], [mm.ymin, mm.ymax]
  x1, y1 = mm(df["LONGITUDE"][df["YEAR"] == years[i]].values, df["LATITUDE"][df["YEAR"] == years[i]].values)
  x += x1.tolist()
  y += y1.tolist()
  x = np.array(x)
  y = np.array(y)
  if prev_layer:
    prev_layer.remove()

  hexlayer = mm.hexbin(x, y, gridsize = 75, bins = 100, mincnt = 0, cmap = 'my_cmap', linewidth = 0)

prev_layer = None
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_hex, interval = 10, frames = range(len(years)), fargs = (prev_layer, ))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would use a global array to store the objects returned by `hexbin()`. At predefined intervals, I would remove those objects, and empty the content of the array, then repeat.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(i):
    x0,y0 = np.random.random(size=(2,))*4-2
    x = np.random.normal(loc=x0, size=(1000,))
    y = np.random.normal(loc=y0, size=(1000,))

    if len(prevlayers)>=maxlayers:
        for layer in prevlayers:
            layer.remove()
        prevlayers[:] = []    

    hexlayer = ax.hexbin(x,y, gridsize=10, alpha=0.5)
    prevlayers.append(hexlayer)
    return hexlayer,

maxlayers = 3
prevlayers = []
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=12)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using this solution with maxlayers = 1 and I got an error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`. Is there a better way to do this for just one layer showing at a time?